# Can't convert string to int (Java)

Tags: java, string, int

For some reason javac can't compile Integer.parseInt(). I tried several programs that have parseInt in them and they don't work so I wrote up a simple little program to test whether the problem is parseInt or something else in the programs. Here's the test program I wrote:

```
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);  
System.out.println(a);

}
}
```

Even with the program above, I still got a compiler error saying: "error: cannot find symbol a = Integer.parseInt();" with an arrow point to the . between Integer and parse. I've tried running the program with Double.parseDouble() and it works just fine. Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error?

Comment: This is not the code that got that error.

Comment: If that's not compiling, then someone hacked your javac.

Comment: Did you make your own class called `Integer` by chance?

Answer (score 2):

Java imports the `java.lang` package for you. All the classes in that package are therefore available to your program without needing to use an `import` statement. If however you have declared a class called `Integer` in your package (the default package), then you are [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) the `Integer` in `java.lang`.

You can use the fully qualified name of the class instead

```
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

Or create your own `static  parseInt(String)` method in your custom `Integer` class. That will make the program compile. Make sure that it does what you want.

Comment: `Or create your own static parseInt(String) method in your custom Integer class` I would highly advise against making a class named `Integer` to begin with, nevermind matching the method names so that we catch less compile-time errors.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Integer.parseInt()`, try:

```
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

This will ensure you definitely use the correct `Integer` class in java.lang - if that doesn't work then there's something seriously wrong with your environment. If it does then you must have another class called `Integer` somewhere that you're implicitly referring to instead of the `java.lang.Integer` class.